# UITableViewCell height issue when tap

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, uicollectionview

I used a custom UITableViewCell with xib. In UITableViewCell I used collection view. all things work good but there is a problem when I expand and collapse cell. What I want to do is when I tap on cell it become expand if it is not else collapsed. I changed constraint for that but its not working , it's working when I tap button twice. my code is :

```
#pragma mark:tbl view delegate data source
-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{
    NSLog(@"%lu",(unsigned long)postArr.count);
    return postArr.count;
}

-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    rewardCell*cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"simpleCellReward"];

     if (cell == nil) {
         cell = [[rewardCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"simpleCellReward"];
     }

     [cell.showRewardBtn addTarget:self action:@selector(showRewards:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

     cell.showRewardBtn.tag = indexPath.row+1;

     cell.collectionContainer.layer.cornerRadius = 3.0;
     cell.collectionContainer.clipsToBounds = true;

     cell.lblTitle.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"My Reward %ld",(long)indexPath.row];

     if (selectIndexForReward == indexPath.row) {
         if (cell.collectionHeightConstraint.constant == 0) {
             cell.collectionHeightConstraint.constant = 97;

         }else{
             cell.collectionHeightConstraint.constant = 0;
         }
     }

     [cell layoutIfNeeded];
     [cell.collectionView layoutIfNeeded];
     return cell;
}



-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    if ((int)indexPath.row == (slot-2)) {
        page = page+1;
        slot = slot+10;

       HUD = [MBProgressHUD showHUDAddedTo:self.view animated:true];

        [apiObj getPostData:@{@"page":[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",page],@"user_id":user.usrid}];
    }
}

-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView estimatedHeightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    return UITableViewAutomaticDimension;
}
-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    return UITableViewAutomaticDimension;
}
```

note: there is more then one custom cell which managed by condition but I need expandable cell in particular custom cell which is written above in code.

above code worked when I tap twice. In cell there is a button on which I set target and using that target I reload table. code for that is

```
#pragma mark:ShowReward
-(void)showRewards:(UIButton*)sender{
    selectIndexForReward= (int)sender.tag-1;
    //[self.tblView reloadData];
    rewardCell *cell =(rewardCell *)sender.superview.superview.superview; //change with your class
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tblView indexPathForCell:cell];
    [self.tblView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Change constraint value in `showReward` method and call `beginUpdate()` and `endUpdate()` methods of tableview.

```
-(void)showRewards:(UIButton*)sender{

rewardCell *cell =(rewardCell *)sender.superview.superview.superview; //change with your class

tableView.beginUpdates()
         if (cell.collectionHeightConstraint.constant == 0) {
             cell.collectionHeightConstraint.constant = 97;

         }else{
             cell.collectionHeightConstraint.constant = 0;
         }
     }
tableView.endUpdates()
}
```